# Duplicate a specific line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to search for a specific string and when the string is found, the whole line should be copied into the next line. And also I need to add to the original string a comment like this:

Example for searchstring "foo"

```
ABCD
ABCD
xxx foo xxx
ABCD
```

Result:

```
ABCD
ABCD
// Next line comes xxx foo xxx
xxx foo xxx
ABCD
```

Comment: You can try to develop your own plugin which does this. Here are some links how to do this http://notepad-plus-plus.org/resources.html :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Maybe I have a look at coding my own plugin :-)

Comment: I use Notepad++ a lot. I'll be looking forward to it.

Comment: `Ctrl + D` Will duplicate a line. But without commenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do:

Find what: `^(.*foo.*)$`
Replace with: `// Next line comes $1\n$1`

Make sure that `Dot matches newline` is not checked.

Comment: Works great! The Replace with looks like this "// Next line comes $1\n$1"